# What would've given more accurate consonant ratios than 12?

Tags: tuning, temperament

So my understanding is 12 notes was chosen in a chromatic scale cause in tuning, the twelfth root of two gives values quite close to simple ratios. For example for a fifth, the twelfth root of 2 raised to the 7th power gives a value really close to 3/2. However there are more accurate numbers right? But we don't use them cause that would've resulted in too many keys on the piano and the successive frequencies not being much discernible. Can you give a few examples of such numbers greater than 12 which also would give values close to the simple consonant ratios?

Comment: There are quite a few other well-known equally-tempered tunings that do so. 19 EDO has an almost perfect minor third, 31 EDO has an almost perfect major third and harmonic seventh, 53 EDO has a perfect fifth that is much closer to JI than in 12 EDO, *et cetera.*

Comment: If you would like to see some of the mathematics behind this ("advanced" but not all that difficult), please allow me to recommend my article [Arithmetic and music in twelve easy steps](https://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/1990-1999/volume-26-1990/issue-1/article/arithmetic-and-music-twelve-easy-steps).

Answer (score 20):

Before there were 12 notes one had 8 different notes (modulo octaves), formed by three different *hexachords*. Since ancient times musicology had the concept of tones and semitones, and these hexachords form notes with steps in tones and semitones. 12 is more or less what you get when you try to fill up the gaps so that all steps are semitones.

So this number 12 actually comes from the concept of a semitone. This is quite unrelated to the whole 12th root of 2 thing, which only came up because intervals defined by rational ratios just didn’t fit together as we wanted to use them.

Now, let’s get to your main question: What other equal divisions of the octave can approximate certain pure intervals similarly well or even better than the 12th root of 2?

Well, first of all that depends on your metric. Let’s say we're given a ratio p/q and a base step f. Then we want log_f(p/q)\ to be close to an integer. In other words if `{.} := . - [.]` is the distance to the next integer, we want

```
|{log_f(p/q)}|
```

to be small. This error is then measured in parts of step f. To make different f comparable we can express this in whole octaves by dividing this difference by log_f(2).

Now, if we fix a set of ratios we want to approximate well (such as 3/2, 4/3, 5/4, 6/5 (just fifth, fourth, maj third, min third) we’d thus get an error vector. This vector could be combined to a single metric in different ways, such as:

- (weighted) sum of the components (1-Norm)
- p-th root of the sum of the (weighted) p-th powers (p-Norm)
- maximum of the components (sup-Norm)

Then we can simply try some options and select the ones that work well. (No need to apply complicated lattice approximations here).

Here for example we are looking at division of the octave into 1 to 1000 parts, with only those cases chosen that perform at least as well as the previous ones:

For 1-Norm (mean):

```
     n          3/2          4/3          5/4          6/5           E1
1    1 4.150375e-01 4.150375e-01 3.219281e-01 2.630344e-01 3.537594e-01
2    2 8.496250e-02 8.496250e-02 1.780719e-01 2.369656e-01 1.462406e-01
3    3 8.170417e-02 8.170417e-02 1.140524e-02 7.029893e-02 6.127812e-02
4    5 1.503750e-02 1.503750e-02 7.807191e-02 6.303441e-02 4.279533e-02
5    7 1.353393e-02 1.353393e-02 3.621381e-02 2.267988e-02 2.149039e-02
6   12 1.629167e-03 1.629167e-03 1.140524e-02 1.303441e-02 6.924495e-03
7   19 6.015132e-03 6.015132e-03 6.138621e-03 1.234889e-04 4.573094e-03
8   31 4.317339e-03 4.317339e-03 6.525503e-04 4.969890e-03 3.564280e-03
9   34 3.272793e-03 3.272793e-03 1.601317e-03 1.671477e-03 2.454595e-03
10  53 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 6.008990e-04
11 106 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 6.008990e-04
12 118 2.167380e-04 2.167380e-04 1.058034e-04 3.225414e-04 2.154552e-04
13 171 1.671791e-04 1.671791e-04 2.906680e-04 1.234889e-04 1.871288e-04
14 289 1.874142e-04 1.874142e-04 1.287869e-04 5.862729e-05 1.405607e-04
15 323 1.768182e-04 1.768182e-04 5.332926e-05 1.234889e-04 1.326136e-04
16 441 7.151288e-05 7.151288e-05 6.736997e-05 4.142919e-06 5.363466e-05
17 559 1.066565e-05 1.066565e-05 7.548293e-05 6.481728e-05 4.040788e-05
18 612 4.819540e-06 4.819540e-06 3.267005e-05 3.748959e-05 1.994968e-05
```

For the 2-Norm:

```
     n          3/2          4/3          5/4          6/5           E2
1    1 4.150375e-01 4.150375e-01 3.219281e-01 2.630344e-01 3.596307e-01
2    2 8.496250e-02 8.496250e-02 1.780719e-01 2.369656e-01 1.599215e-01
3    3 8.170417e-02 8.170417e-02 1.140524e-02 7.029893e-02 6.786597e-02
4    5 1.503750e-02 1.503750e-02 7.807191e-02 6.303441e-02 5.128550e-02
5    7 1.353393e-02 1.353393e-02 3.621381e-02 2.267988e-02 2.341021e-02
6   12 1.629167e-03 1.629167e-03 1.140524e-02 1.303441e-02 8.736183e-03
7   19 6.015132e-03 6.015132e-03 6.138621e-03 1.234889e-04 5.245511e-03
8   31 4.317339e-03 4.317339e-03 6.525503e-04 4.969890e-03 3.949825e-03
9   34 3.272793e-03 3.272793e-03 1.601317e-03 1.671477e-03 2.587489e-03
10  53 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 8.108535e-04
11 106 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 8.108535e-04
12 118 2.167380e-04 2.167380e-04 1.058034e-04 3.225414e-04 2.286799e-04
13 171 1.671791e-04 1.671791e-04 2.906680e-04 1.234889e-04 1.972531e-04
14 289 1.874142e-04 1.874142e-04 1.287869e-04 5.862729e-05 1.502260e-04
15 323 1.768182e-04 1.768182e-04 5.332926e-05 1.234889e-04 1.419708e-04
16 441 7.151288e-05 7.151288e-05 6.736997e-05 4.142919e-06 6.079486e-05
17 559 1.066565e-05 1.066565e-05 7.548293e-05 6.481728e-05 5.031517e-05
18 612 4.819540e-06 4.819540e-06 3.267005e-05 3.748959e-05 2.509610e-05
19 730 3.099387e-05 3.099387e-05 1.028667e-05 2.070720e-05 2.477824e-05
```

For the maximum norm:

```
     n          3/2          4/3          5/4          6/5         Emax
1    1 4.150375e-01 4.150375e-01 3.219281e-01 2.630344e-01 4.150375e-01
2    2 8.496250e-02 8.496250e-02 1.780719e-01 2.369656e-01 2.369656e-01
3    3 8.170417e-02 8.170417e-02 1.140524e-02 7.029893e-02 8.170417e-02
4    5 1.503750e-02 1.503750e-02 7.807191e-02 6.303441e-02 7.807191e-02
5    7 1.353393e-02 1.353393e-02 3.621381e-02 2.267988e-02 3.621381e-02
6   12 1.629167e-03 1.629167e-03 1.140524e-02 1.303441e-02 1.303441e-02
7   19 6.015132e-03 6.015132e-03 6.138621e-03 1.234889e-04 6.138621e-03
8   31 4.317339e-03 4.317339e-03 6.525503e-04 4.969890e-03 4.969890e-03
9   34 3.272793e-03 3.272793e-03 1.601317e-03 1.671477e-03 3.272793e-03
10  53 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 1.173378e-03
11 106 5.684034e-05 5.684034e-05 1.173378e-03 1.116538e-03 1.173378e-03
12 118 2.167380e-04 2.167380e-04 1.058034e-04 3.225414e-04 3.225414e-04
13 171 1.671791e-04 1.671791e-04 2.906680e-04 1.234889e-04 2.906680e-04
14 289 1.874142e-04 1.874142e-04 1.287869e-04 5.862729e-05 1.874142e-04
15 323 1.768182e-04 1.768182e-04 5.332926e-05 1.234889e-04 1.768182e-04
16 441 7.151288e-05 7.151288e-05 6.736997e-05 4.142919e-06 7.151288e-05
17 612 4.819540e-06 4.819540e-06 3.267005e-05 3.748959e-05 3.748959e-05
18 730 3.099387e-05 3.099387e-05 1.028667e-05 2.070720e-05 3.099387e-05
```

So we do not really see a difference in what metric we are using, apart from the 2-Norm and the maximum gaining n = 730, which is due to 612 being quite uneven (the 2-Norm puts more weight on larger values; the maximum norm only depends on the largest value. The 1-Norm on the other hand is most sensitive to small values).

We see that using n = 12 drastically improves the approximation as compared to the previous values, while later values only offer slight improvements. The next option would be n = 19, which does exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19_equal_temperament

Then we get a big hole, and another slight improvement at n = 31, which does also exist: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/31_equal_temperament

You might also want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament

Comment: 53 is nice too.

Comment: 19 and 34 also have some nice ratios (in addition to 31 and 53)

Comment: Thanks that helped :). OK so basically I was creating a science project video about consonance dissonance and tuning systems. So is it wrong to like first explain pythagorean tuning then mention the flaws and then move onto equal temperament and show the maximum simple ratios are covered for 12, 19 etc. But 19 and 31 often lead to too many notes so 12 is used as the standard? Like to give a logical explanation is this a wrong approach?

Comment: @Betelgeuse2051 I’d start with pythagorean tuning, gregorian chant (organa), the benefit of just fifths and and the disadvantage of unjust major thirds. Then go on to just tuning and its practical shortcomings. Then you can explain meantone tuning (which incidently naturally prefers the 19 tone ET, as 12 tone ET gives a rather bad approximation of the just major 3rd) and tempered tunings, leading to modern equal temperament. Then you can explore alternative divisions of the octave and their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @Lazy that's a nice structure. But actually I have a 2 min time limit haha. And since its a science competition I need to focus more on the math aspect tham the musical one. Its gonna be quite difficult to encompass all of that in 2 minutes. So yeah I wanted to explain mathematically the basic concept without going much into musical analysis. Besides I have to keep the consonance dissonance part (simple complex ratios) in the beginning to help explain the tuning part. So that's a major time problem

Comment: Those tables would be a lot more readable if the errors where given in cents, rounded to whole.

Comment: And is it just coincidence that 19 + 34 = 53?

Answer (score 3):

The 12-pitch chromatic scale preceded equal temperament, so the 12th root of 2 was chosen because there were already 12 pitches, not the other way around. Loosely speaking, as you increase the number of pitches, the ratios will grow increasingly closer to their ideal values.

Comment: "as you increase the number of pitches, the ratios will grow increasingly closer to their ideal values": this is not at all true, as a few minutes with a spreadsheet will show.

Comment: @phoog it seems mathematically obvious that as the divisions of the octave grow larger, the availability of pitches near specific ratios will increase. In the limit, there will be perfect correspondences.

Comment: @phoog It is a thing of lattice approximation. If the distance between two notes is 1/k octaves then any note can be approximated with at least a precision of 1/(2k). So as long as you keep increasing resolution the precision will get arbitrarily fine, which is what Aaron pointed at. What he is not claiming is that this is monotonic, so that having more notes willl always mean more precision.

Comment: @Lazy Or, rather, having more notes will *eventually* mean more precision; however, the precision will be different amongst different intervals.

Comment: Though it is true that full chromatic runs can be found already in 16th century music, I nevertheless object to the statement that there was already "The 12-pitch chromatic scale" then. You can say that it was known that a whole tone was roughly twice the size of a semitone, but this was for a long time more treated as a funny coincidence rather than as a principle that a whole tone consists in any proper sense of two steps.

Comment: "it seems mathematically obvious that as the divisions of the octave grow larger": yet 14-tone ET isn't a better approximation than 12-tone ET.  @Lazy the "loosely speaking" isn't sufficient to clarify that, as your answer shows, there are only two finer equal divisions of the octave that offer closer approximations while being usable (and one of those only questionably so); the third has too many to be practical. In other words, increasing n 31 times, from 12 to 53, gives you 3 better systems and 28 that are not better. The general statement is meaningless in the realm of the practical.

Comment: @leftaroundabout yet the 12-tone keyboard was the common arrangement in the sixteenth century.  The idea that G sharp and A flat were differently tuned versions of the same key on a 12-pitch keyboard (or the same fret on a lute or viol) didn't come out of nowhere in the baroque period.  (Also, this answer does not claim that the 12-pitch chromatic scale arose in the 16th century, only that it arose before equal temperament.)

Comment: Oops, 53-12 is 41, not 31.

Comment: @phoog I think you are misinterpreting my tables. My tables only show results that are better than all of the previous. If we take all that are better than n = 12 we’d get n = 12, 19, 22, 24, 27, 29, 31, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, ... So in fact "only" n = 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 30, 32, 35, 36 perform worse than 12. Note that Emax for n = 12 here is 0.013034406, and 1 / (2*0.013034406) = 38.36?, so starting with n = 39 the approximation is necessarily better than n = 12.

Comment: @Lazy 12 is not better than 12; it's as good as 12. Similarly, 24 is also not better than 12 (because none of the 12 added pitch classes is closer to any desired ratio than the 12 already present in 12-TET).  Yes, 38 is better than 12, but it's not better than 19.  Look for example at 53 and 106: they are equal in all three of your tables.

Comment: Sure, I should have said "not worse". But that is not the point in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say specifically *which* simple ratios you want to approximate, so I'll focus on the three that are part of the 4:5:6 just major triad:

- perfect fifth (P5) = 3/2
- major third (M3) = 5/4
- minor third (m3) = 6/5

Let *n* be the number of equal divisions of the octave (EDO).  Let *x* = round(log<sub>2</sub>(3/2) * x) be the number of EDO steps assigned to a P5.  Then, based on the Circle of Fifths, the M3 is 4x-2n EDO steps, while m3 is 2n-3x EDO steps.  For example, with the familiar [n=12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_equal_temperament) tuning, we get P5=7, M3=4, and m3=3 EDO steps.

I shall assume that n ≥ 7 (so that all the notes of the major scale can be distinct) and n ≤ 100 (for a reasonable but arbitrary upper bound).

To optimize the P5 interval, we wish to find *n* so that the fraction x/n is as close to the theoretical log<sub>2</sub>(3/2) ≈ 0.584963 as possible.  It turns out that the best values of *n* are:

1. 53 (error: 0.068 [cent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cent_(music)))
2. 94 (0.173)
3. 65 (0.417)
4. 41 or 82 (0.484)
5. 77 (0.656)
6. 89 (0.831)
7. 70 (0.902)
8. 99 (1.075)
9. 29, 58, or 87 (1.493)
10. 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, or 96 (1.955)

To optimize M3, we want to find (4x-2n)/n as close to log<sub>2</sub>(5/4) ≈ 0.321928 as possible.  The best values of *n* are:

1. 31, 62, or 93 (0.783)
2. 81 (1.129)
3. 50 or 100 (2.314)
4. 74 (2.875)
5. 69 (3.705)
6. 43 or 86 (4.384)
7. 88 (4.496)
8. 98 (5.523)
9. 55 (6.414)
10. 19, 38, 57, or 76 (7.366)

And to optimize the m3 interval, we want to find (2n-3x)/n as close to log<sub>2</sub>(6/5) ≈ 0.263034 as possible.  The best values of *n* are:

1. 19, 38, 57, or 76 (0.148)
2. 88 (2.005)
3. 69 (2.598)
4. 64 (3.109)
5. 50 or 100 (3.641)
6. 45 (4.359)
7. 81 (4.530)
8. 31, 62, or 93 (5.964)
9. 26 or 52 (7.436)
10. 74 (7.533)

You can't simultaneously optimize all three intervals, so we'll have to compromise.  How can we combine these results to get an "overall" optimum?  One way is to simply add the errors for the three intervals, giving:

1. 81 (11.317)
2. 50 or 100 (11.910)
3. 31, 62, or 93 (11.928)
4. 69 (12.606)
5. 88 (13.001)

If we use the sums of *squared* errors (in cents), then we get the slightly-different ranking:

1. 81 (53.817)
2. 50 or 100 (54.074)
3. 69 (60.201)
4. 31, 62, or 93 (63.022)
5. 88 (66.485)

So, in conclusion:

- [19 divisions per octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19_equal_temperament) gives the most accurate minor thirds.
- [31 divisions per octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/31_equal_temperament) gives the most accurate major thirds.
- [53 divisions per octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/53_equal_temperament) gives the most accurate perfect fifths.
- 81 divisions per octave gives a good compromise between the three intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem in music tuning (temperament) is finding ratios of intervals that allow for combining 2 whole steps into a major third. The "ideal" whole step is (according to Just Tuning) 9/8 so a major third becomes (9/8)*(9/8) or 81/64 but the Just Tuning ratio for a major is 5/4 (80/64). Similar problems arise for other intervals (whether used melodically or harmonically).

Mathematically, one ends up trying to find numbers (A/B)^N=2. Taking A=18, B=17, and N=12 was suggested by Vincenzo Galilei for fretted or keyed instruments. No other B smaller than 18 is as good (with the same N). There are no exact solutions (proved about 2002 but guessed earlier).

Here are some papers on the subject.

https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/bartha.pdf
https://www.parabola.unsw.edu.au/files/articles/2020-2029/volume-57-2021/issue-2/vol57_no2_1.pdf
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jack-Douthett/publication/12488526_Construction_and_interpretation_of_equal-tempered_scales_using_frequency_ratios_maximally_even_sets_and_P-cycles/links/54203b350cf241a65a1b7740/Construction-and-interpretation-of-equal-tempered-scales-using-frequency-ratios-maximally-even-sets-and-P-cycles.pdf